# Assert function reacting invalid - Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am facing a problem in my script. Below is my function code for searching a term.

```
//Function that gets the text of the search result descriptive line
public String getSearchResultQuery()
    {
        return driver.findElement(searchResult).getText();
    }

public void querySearchBox(String searchTerm) throws Exception
    {
        driver.findElement(searchBox).sendKeys(searchTerm);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //System.out.println(getSearchResultQuery()); -----> Printed out (Knowledge Base for "relative")
        //System.out.println(driver.findElement(searchResult).getText()); -----> Printed out (Knowledge Base for "relative")
        //System.out.println("Knowledge Base for \"" + searchTerm + "\""); -----> Printed out (Knowledge Base for "relative")

        Thread.sleep(20000);

        if(!(getSearchResultQuery().contains("Knowledge Base for \"" + searchTerm + "\"")));
        {
            Assert.fail("Verify Search Results. Something's not right");
        }
    }
```

I know Thread.sleep() is a bad practice but I am just trying to make my test work at the moment and will optimize my code later.

The issue is that when I enter the term "relative", it shows the results as expected but my block is giving the wrong output.

```
if(!(getSearchResultQuery().contains("Knowledge Base for \"" + searchTerm + "\"")));
            {
                Assert.fail("Verify Search Results. Something's not right");
            }
```

It should not fail my assertion here as everything is working as expeced. In my above code I tried to see the outputs through console, and all of them are giving valid returns. But then why my assertion is failing, if the following is not wrong.

```
if(!(getSearchResultQuery().contains("Knowledge Base for \"" + searchTerm + "\"")))
```

**EDITED:**
My searchResult is the xpath of the line that says (Knowledge Base for "relative").

```
By searchResult = By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/featured-studies-grid/div[2]/search-results-container/div[1]/div[1]");
```

This line does not exist before search result compilation. It only exists when user enters something in the search box.

Comment: The million-dollar question: Where does the variable `searchResult` come from, inside `getSearchResultQuery()`? Is it getting modified if this method is called multiple times?

Comment: The $500,000 question: Is there any intermediary whitespace in the page surrounding whatever logic generates it?

Comment: The $2 question: Are you submitting a form after sending the keystrokes to the search box element? Should you be?

Comment: The 50-cent question: Is it plugged in? Does your current webdriver have Javascript enabled?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja 
Answer to the million dollar question: searchResult contains the xpath of the line that says (Knowledge Base for "relative"), so in my first function String getSearchResultQuery(), I am getting the text of the 
line that shows the information about search results. 

One thing more, this line does not exist before I enter the term in search box. It only generates after search is compile

Comment: There is no need to submit the form, search results show up as soon as user enters something in the search box

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. You've tested it to make sure that your search term is giving you results? Those commented-out lines, they actually run?

Comment: Did you copy-paste your code and expected results into your question, or rewrite it? Just make sure that what you're getting back from `getSearchResultQuery()` is actually identical to what you expect; hidden characters, whitespace, capitalization, etc. could all affect your if-statement and are easily missed.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Yeah, I tested those commented out lines, all are giving me the right result. 
Is there a way to trim out all the space on the right of the line, so I can test that too, if that is causing the issue or not

Comment: `String.trim()` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your searchResult and getSearchResultQuery(). I am assuming that all things is set by you is fine. Many time concatenation of string create problem .Now try below code:-

```
String mytext="Knowledge Base for \"" + searchTerm + "\"";
if(!(getSearchResultQuery().contains(mytext)))
{
    Assert.fail("Verify Search Results. Something's not right");
}
```

Comment: `getSearchResultQuery()` is actually listed at the top of the OP's question; it threw me off initially as well, I kept looking for it down below. The other issue, of `searchResult` not being known, still stands.

Comment: Please see the edited portion of my original post for searchResult

Answer (score 0):

Does `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(locator, text)` not work for you instead of `Thread.sleep()`?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible things to check:

1. Make sure that the expected result really contains the " char as you declared here: Knowledge Base for "relative".
2. Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems your site is using ajax for the search. Please make sure that you get the ajax response correctly. You could use some kind of condition that checks when all the ajax communications are done to avoid the Thread.sleep() in the future.